# why is the blur not affecting this part

Tags: javascript, html, css

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBpAy.png)

I made a mouse trailer by watching this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kySGqoU7X-s
when i made a div to make the text and other stuff to add the area with the div just doesn't show the blur i tried using z-index but didn't work... i am kind of new so idk what else to try. I need this for my portfolio .

**CSS**

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0rem;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.text{
    color:aquamarine;
    z-index : 99;
}

@keyframes rotate {
from {
    rotate: 0deg;
}

50% {
    scale: 1 1.5;
}

to {
    rotate: 360deg;
}
}

#blob {
background-color: white;
height: 34vmax;
aspect-ratio: 1;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
translate: -50% -50%;
border-radius: 50%;
background: linear-gradient(to right, aquamarine, mediumpurple);
animation: rotate 20s infinite;
opacity: 0.8;
}

#blur {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
backdrop-filter: blur(12vmax);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
const blob = document.getElementById("blob");

window.onpointermove = event => { 
  const { clientX, clientY } = event;
  
  blob.animate({
    left: `${clientX}px`,
    top: `${clientY}px`
  }, { duration: 3000, fill: "forwards" });
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>PORTfolio</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="header">

            </div>

            <div class="text">          
                <h1>Found me?</h1>
                <button>Know more then</button>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <div id="blob"></div>
                <div id="blur"></div>    
            </div>

    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on SO.
First, you were close to your goal.
You had to set the `top:0;` on your blur div, to catch the top of the screen.

But if you do that, you'll see that the blur and blob are on the front of your text, i will suggest to adjust your `z-index`, exemple in this spinnet : `z-index:-3;` for the blob, and `z-index:-2;` for the blur.

To resume :

`top:0;` and `z-index:-2` on the blur
`z-index:-3` on the blob

```js
const blob = document.getElementById("blob");

window.onpointermove = event => { 
  const { clientX, clientY } = event;
  
  blob.animate({
    left: `${clientX}px`,
    top: `${clientY}px`
  }, { duration: 3000, fill: "forwards" });
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0rem;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.text{
    color:aquamarine;
    z-index : 99;
}

@keyframes rotate {
from {
    rotate: 0deg;
}

50% {
    scale: 1 1.5;
}

to {
    rotate: 360deg;
}
}

#blob {
background-color: white;
height: 34vmax;
aspect-ratio: 1;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
translate: -50% -50%;
border-radius: 50%;
z-index:-3;
background: linear-gradient(to right, aquamarine, mediumpurple);
animation: rotate 20s infinite;
opacity: 0.8;
}

#blur {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top:0;
z-index: -2;
backdrop-filter: blur(12vmax);
}
```

```html
            <div class="text">          
                <h1>Found me?</h1>
                <button>Know more then</button>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <div id="blob"></div>
                <div id="blur"></div>    
            </div>
```